# Getting name of SQL Servers

Tags: c#, sql-server

Is there a way to get names of SQL database servers (Server Name) we have in our network?
The closest I found is the link below, tested it. It is printing the name of computers of my coworkers on the network!

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sql.sqldatasourceenumerator.getdatasources(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: are you sure they don't actually have sql server installed on their machines?

Comment: @Jay  They all do have SQL Server installed on their machines. But that's not what I want. I want the SQL Server names on the network that we call connect to them, not these local ones of other people.

Comment: Those api's just do a shout on the network and they all responded. If you want a smaller list you're going to have to filter it yourself. Those "local ones" are still SQL server instances and provided the firewall has been correctly configured you can connect to them over the network as well. SQL server cannot read your mind because you're basically saying "I want all SQL Servers except that I don't want all SQL Servers".

Answer (score 0):

If your SQL instances have the SQL Browser service up and running, you can use this one-liner in Powershell to list them:

```
[System.Data.Sql.SqlDataSourceEnumerator]::Instance.GetDataSources()
```

If this is not the case you can use `sqlcmd` to list all instances in your local network:

```
sqlcmd -L
```

Or alternatively `osql -L`

Please note that both methods will just return the server name if SQL Server has been installed as default instance and neither method are guaranteed to return all SQL Server instances in your network.

Comment: returned the same result as what I had.  Although in a prettier format.

Comment: Please note that both methods will return the server name if SQL Server has been installed as the default instance

Answer (score 0):

The easiest to get all active sql servers are explained in the following blog.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sushilc/archive/2004/10/14/242395.aspx